# The continuation token specified in the request is malformed in cosmosDB

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to execute a stored procedure which accepts continuationToken and does the pagination. I am executing this SP from Azure portal. I have forced the results to 1 JSON document per execution so that I get the continuationToken and I can pass the same execution token and do the second run.

When I pass the continuationToken from 1st run to the 2nd run as a parameter, it says "The continuation token specified in the request is malformed.Please re-run the query without it and iterate"

I checked for some help online but mostly errors around this included range values also in the token. In my case, I do not have any range values. The token looks like its been run in single partition only. Below is the token

`'+RID:IjI7AKy72+8MAAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:1#FPC:AQwAAAAAAAAADQAAAAAAAAA='`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer
When passing this parameter, it should be passed as type 'String' and without any quotes enclosing the value. This problem is only happens when running from Azure portal.

Comment: Could you please help on this? I didn't get any clarification on your answer. I am facing the same issue again.